# Meaning of "#define something p##n" in a CUDA header

Tags: c++, c, cuda

I've encountered the following line in a .cuh file:

```
#define mp_ptr(n)     P##n
```

What does the `P##n` part mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means concatenation. It's a C preprocessor directive.

So, `mp_ptr(1)` becomes `P1`, `mp_ptr("foobar")` becomes `P"foobar"`, etc.

Comment: And it can only be used when defining a preprocessor macro.

Comment: Note that `##` is commonly known as the "token-pasting" operator - I mention this as it helps with Google searches etc.